# How to find the rest of the data that I did not choose?

Tags: matlab

I have 100 datasets and I need to choose only 50 datasets randomly from the 100. I use randperm function from MatLab. It works well.

```
nimages=100;
nsample=50;
train=randperm(nimages);
newtrain=train(1:nsample);
```

How can I find the rest of the data, the other 50 data sets that I did not choose?

what if I use function Randi
nimages=100;

nsample=50;

train=randi(nimages,nsample,1);

x=train(:,1);

how can I get the rest of the data?

Comment: `setdiff(1:nimages,newtrain)`

Comment: `train(nsample+1:end)`

Comment: first many thanks for the answer, yes it works, but if I used function randi

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments there are various ways to do this.

The most simple and efficient one should be the solution provided by @Luis Mendo (minus a small typo):

```
train(nsample+1:end)
```